# Moving elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of objects and i want to add elements in this array and simultaneously sort them in ascending order.Although I tried many compinations , I always take a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Here is a part of my code :

```
public boolean insert(Person p)
{
    for(int i=0;i<=size();i++)
    {   
        if (c==0)
        {   
            array[0] = p;
            c++;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {   
            if (p.compareTo(array[i])==-1)
            {
                array[i]=p;
                c++;
                for(int j = size(); j>i; j--)
                {
                    array[j]=array[j-1];
                }
            }
            else if((p.compareTo(array[i])==1))
            {
                array[i+1]=p;
                c++;
                for (int j=(size()-1);j>= i+1; j--)
                {
                    array[j+1]=array[j];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private int c;
private Person array[];
public SortedPersonList()
{   
    this.array = new Person[c];
}
public int size()
    {
        return c;
    }
```

Comment: Use a TreeSet<Person>. It will do that for you, and do it much faster.

Comment: if size() == array.length, than you are accessing array[array.length], which is illegal.

Comment: Library solutions - best solutions! Specially for more or less common things. Though using a TreeSet is slightly misguided, since the data structure at hand is an array and allows multiple equal objects

Comment: size() actually is c.

Comment: @DiVeRsi0n: And how do you initialize the array? It probably needs to be resized, otherwise the capacity is bounded.

Comment: @Ordous: it looks like the posted code doesn't insert a person in the array when the comparison is 0. So a TreeSet would do fine.

Comment: If duplicates are allowed, then use Arrays.binarySearch().

Comment: @DiVeRsi0n: c starts with the default value 0. Your array has therefore a fixed size 0...

Comment: @JBNizet  i am not allowed to use java.util.Arrays or java.util.ArrayList

Comment: @EyalSchneider I have to create an array which has not fixed size... in which way is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You are initializing your array to a size 0, and you never resize it. An array has a fixed size, so in order to populate it with items beyond its range, you should first create a larger array and copy the contents to it (This is how [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) works).

2) When you find the insertion point, you shouldn't override this position before keeping its value in a temp variable. (Also, I don't understand the third case in your code. Why do you insert if p is greater than array[i]? you should rethink your logic.)

3) you may want to use binary search to find the insertion point. It has a better performance than linear search.

Comment: I must insert every time the main method calls the insert(), apart from the case that already a same object already exists in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the equal sign in `for(int i=0;i<=size();i++)`. That is, change to

```
for(int i=0;i<size();i++)
```

Array indices go from `0` to `size-1`. So `array[size()]` is outside the array. Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code :

```
    for(int i=0;i<=size();i++)
```

Write like

```
    for(int i=0;i<size();i++)  or  for(int i=0;i<=size()-1;i++)
```